# What Ubuntu version should I use

Tags: windows-7

What Ubuntu version should I use? Here are the specs.

- Intel Celeron 2.80Ghz Processor
- LGA775 socket motherboard (Asus P5PE-VM)
- 2GB RAM
- 80GB Hard Drive
- Intel 865G + Intel ICH5 Chipset
- Intel Extreme Graphics 2

Thanks in advance
Bombet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a celeron processor and only 2 gigs of ram your computer will run better with lubuntu or xubuntu.[lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) or [xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) 32bit version. You could run ubuntu 32bit version but it will be slower then the other two.

It is not a matter of which one is better both are good but lubuntu will use the least resources so it will be a little faster and snappier.

Just make a livecd or liveusb of both and test for yourself to make sure everything works but remember the live version will be slower then when it is installed.

Comment: Which one is better lubuntu or xubuntu?

Comment: Added more information.

Comment: You should use linux mint 17 cinnamon 32 bit. It's runs well on my Pentium d 945 with nvidia gt 8600 with 250GB ssd and 4GB ram. It runs as well as a new computer as long as I don't watch anything higher than 1080p on it. It doesn't slow down or lag at all.

Answer (score -1):

14.04 LTS is the latest version. 13.10 support will end in 4 days, settings can be changed to allow faster use though you might want to look at ZorinOS. It is basically a Ubuntu shell, uses all the same commands and repositories but is much faster in my experience